# Ruby Search Nokogiri for element

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to search for some information from a website using Nokogiri.  The page is really large and has many different elements.  How do you search for an element that is within some javascript code.  Here's an example below.  For example, I want to search for the value of legislators.email2104

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('www.mywebsite'))
```

## this is part of the information in the doc object.

```
<script language=\"JavaScript\"><![CDATA[<!--     \n \nvar NN4 = document.layers? true : false;  var IE4 = document.all? true : false;  var id = '1164';var legislators = new Object();legislators.fname2128 = \"Neil\";legislators.lname2128 = \"Anderson\";legislators.email2128 = \"nanderson@house.idaho.gov\";legislators.title2128 = \"Representative\";legislators.fname2104 = \"Robert\";legislators.lname2104 = \"Anderst\";legislators.email2104 = \"randerst@house.idaho.gov\";legislators.title2104 = \"Representative\";legislators.fname2 = \"Ken\";legislators.lname2 = \"Andrus\";legislators.email2 = \"kandrus@house.idaho.gov\";legislators.title2 = \"Representative\";legislators.fname3524 = \"Kelly
```

Comment: The code inside the script element will be taken as CDATA (text that contains HTML entities as it is, useful for codes), i.e. the content inside it won't be parsed as HTML, but will be parsed as text so you can't use any xpath or css search to find things inside the content. So I think you will probably have to get the text, and use any of the  string searching methods available in ruby to find the email address.

Comment: Can you pls help me figure out how to get the text out?  Here's some of the HTML before the javascript.  There are many, many other HTML lines of code prior to this.

Comment: <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"collection\" value=\"Current Legislation\"/>&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n\t </form>&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n&#13;\n      </td>&#13;\n    </tr>&#13;\n  </table>&#13;\n  </div>&#13;\n     </td><td width=\"95%\" valign=\"top\"><a name=\"skipnav\" class=\"skipnav\"><img src=\"/images/spacer.gif\" alt=\"\" width=\"2\" height=\"1\" border=\"0\"/></a><script language=\"JavaScript\"><![CDATA[<!--     \n \nvar NN4 = document.layers? true : false;  var IE4 = document.all? true : false;  var id = '1164';var legislator

Comment: If it's okay, can you link the website ? The script element doesn't have anything unique to it to fetch it directly, so even if we get a working solution it will based on its positioning, but it will make it very much vulnerable to breaking. UPDATE : If you can't post the link, try to find the closest parent element of it with some kind of id or name.

Comment: Here's the link http://legislature.idaho.gov/about/contactmembersform.cfm?ID=45

Comment: You can use this to get the code inside the script element : `code = doc.at('//table/tbody/tr').search('./td')[1].at('./script')`. Now you can use something like : `code.text.scan(/legislators.email\d+[^;]+;/)` to get the email ids (you can replace `\d+` with 2104 if you only want that particular email id.

Comment: I tried doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://legislature.idaho.gov/about/contactmembersform.cfm?ID=45'))
but code = doc.at('//table/tbody/tr')  is nil

Comment: Got it work using this code = doc.at('//table/tr').search('./td')[1].at('./script')
Thanks for your help!